# Rewriting a harmonic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-functions, harmonic-numbers, euler-mascheroni-constant

Anyone to help me rewrite this :
$$\sum _{n=1}^{p}\:\frac{x}{\left(6n-1\right)}\:+\:\frac{x}{\left(6n+1\right)}$$

Where,  $p=\left\lfloor \frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{6}\right\rfloor$

to this ( approximations that are easily computed) :

$$xH(x) \approx x (\ln x+\gamma )-\frac{1}{12 x}+\frac{1}{2}$$
Where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma\approx 0.577215665$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

I think that I should first consider separately
$$S_p=\sum _{n=1}^{p}\:\frac{x}{\left(6n-1\right)}\:+\:\frac{x}{\left(6n+1\right)}=\frac{\log (432)-6}{6} x +\frac{H_{p-\frac{1}{6}}+H_{p+\frac{1}{6}}}{6} x $$ and
$$p=\left\lfloor \frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{6}\right\rfloor$$ to show a series of discontinuous straight lines changing slope.

Comment: Merci Claude, c'est gentil

Comment: @Billysenders. If $x=161$, $p=1$ and $H_{p+\frac{1}{6}}=H_{\frac{7}{6}}\sim 1.10223$